# how can I make wso2 polled by antother instance of WSO2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, ibm-api-management

I need to plug a wso2 gateway on another wso2 gateway (throught a proxy, but that's not the pb). How can I make the 1st wso2 be authenticated on the 2nd one with an API_KEY ?
Actually the 2nd one is on Prototype mode to be accessed.

Perhaps someone have the solution ?
Thanks !
Bruno

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a customer header to second API Manager which act as prototype.

Here is the summery of the flow

Client (headers: Authorization, custom) -> Gateway (drop: Authorization, convert: custom->Authorization) -> Backend

More information can be found [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Pass+a+Custom+Authorization+Token+to+the+Backend)

Comment: Hi Abimaran, This solution is working good. This is the way we work today. But this can't be the final version. Because it means that the 2nd WSO2 is in "full open" mode without any security. So I need to have a way to pass an API_KEY (OAuth token) from the 1st one. Is it possible to pass a token after wso2 authentication ? (mean add a token in the http header ?)